# cannot remove half installed app

Tags: apt, upgrade, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

please help me to fix this

`sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/21.6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error processing package macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7 (--configure):
 package macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
Errors were encountered while processing:
 macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get purge macbuntu-os-icons-lts-v7` to remoive the package and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands in a terminal

```
sudo apt-get autoremove  
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Now start your installation